# If the centralizer of an element of a group is abelian, then can two elements inside it be conjugates?

Tags: group-theory

I have a small doubt, which might be trivial too. But I am unable to see it. Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes such that  $q \ | \ p-1.$ Consider the group $G = A \rtimes \langle b \rangle$, where $A$ is a finite $p$-group and $b$ is of order $q.$ If we have the group ring $FG$ over the field $F$ with p elements, then its unit group $\mathcal{U}(FG)$ turns out to be of the form $(1+I) \rtimes \mathcal{U}(F \langle b \rangle),$ where I is an ideal of $FG$ and $1+I$ is a p-group. Here the centralizer of $b$ in $1+I, C_{1+I}(b),$ turns out to be an abelian group. Then is it possible that for two elements $z_i, z_j \in C_{1+I}(b),$ there exists some $u \in \mathcal{U}(FG)$ such that $u^{-1}z_iu = z_j?$

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question exactly. Also, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Like...pick your favourite small primes and try something.

Comment: @Shaun. z_i and z_j are commuting and I am asking can they be conjugates or not. I did not get what are you trying to say. Please clarify.

Comment: @mathseeker I suspect he is saying that there is no immediate reason why the centraliser is an abelian group. Also, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Nowhere in the title do you say that $z_1,z_2\in C_A(b)$. Nowhere have you shown your thoughts on the question at hand. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Actually the group I am working with is satisfying the above assumptions. It is the unit group of a group ring and all that I said above is holding true there.

Comment: I think now the title is more self-explanatory.

Comment: That's better, but the main problem is the lack of context.

Comment: But the question does not seem to be particularly easy. I am going to vote to reopen. (I am assuming that the $C_A(b)$ abelian is intended to be an assumption, although that is not clear.)

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't know why has it been closed and how to reopen it. It is a nice group theoretic exercise.

Comment: @mathseeker to reopen your question you should edit it to include some of: background and motivation, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important. I mean, if you expanded your above comment about your group being the unit group of a ring, that would probably be enough. Also, the question doesn't make sense (as presumably the centraliser being abelian is an *assumption* - it is not true in general).

Comment: @user1729 Yes, the centralizer being abelian is just an assumption in a particular case.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can it be reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $G = P \rtimes Q$ (I have renamed your $A$ as $P$) with $P$ a finite $p$-group, and $Q = \langle b \rangle$ cyclic of order $q$ with $q|p-1$, and we are assuming that $C := C_P(b)$ is abelian. I will attempt to prove that it is impossible for distinct elements $x,y \in C$ to be conjugate in $G$, and we will work by induction on $P$. I am afraid that my proof is somewhat lengthy!

Since $b$ centralizes $x$ and $y$, if they are conjugate then they must be conjugate by an element $g \in P$. So clearly $P$ cannot be abelian.

Now $b$ normalizes the characteristic subgroup $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ of $P$ (i.e. the elements of order $1$ or $p$ in $Z(P)$). Since $q|p-1$, the irreducible modules for $Q$ in characteristic $p$ have dimension $1$, so $Q$ normalizes some subgroup $\langle z \rangle$ of $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ of order $p$. Let $Z = \langle z \rangle$.

We will use the general result that, if a finite group $Q$ of order coprime to the prime $p$ acts on a $p$-group $P$, then $P = C_P(Q)[P,Q]$.

Let $D/Z := C_{P/Z}(b)$. Then applying the above result to the action of $Q$ on $D$, we have $[Q,D] \le Z$, so $D=CZ$. In particular, $D/Z$ is abelian, and by inductive hypothesis applied to $P/Z \rtimes Q$, two distinct elements of $D/Z$ cannot be conjugate, and so we must have $xZ = yZ$. We can assume that $y=xz$ (which implies that $C=D$).

Now let $X = C_P(x)$. Since $g^{-1}xg = y = xz$, and $g \not\in X$, but the image $gZ$ of $g$ in $P/Z$ lies in the subgroup $Y$ with $Y/Z = C_P(xZ)$. Since $x$ has at most $p$ conjugates in $Y$, we must have $|Y:X| = p$, and $Y = \langle X,g \rangle$. Furthermore, since $b$ centralizes $x$, it normalizes both $X$ and $Y$.

We have $b^{-1}gb = g^kw$ for some $k$ with $1 \le k \le p-1$ and $w \in X$. Then $g^{-1}xg=xz$ implies that $(g^kw)^{-1}x(g^kw) = g^{-k}xg^k = xz$. But $g^{-k}xg^k = xz^k$, so $k=1$.

So $b$ centralizes $Y/X$, but then by the result above applied to the action of $Q$ on $Y$, we have $[Q,Y] \le X$ and $Y = C_Y(Q)[Q,Y]$, so some element $gv$ with $v \in X$ must lie in $C_P(b)$. But $C_P(b)$ is abelian, so $gv$ and hence also $g$ must centralize $x$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I wanted to let you know that Q in my question is U(Fb), not the cyclic group generated by b. But all the elements of P which commute with b, also commute with any element of U(Fb). Would it make a difference to the solution provided by you? Further, I request you to let me know why would there exist some subgroup Z of the characteristic subgroup which would be normalized by Q.

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to answer your original question, which didn't mention $U(Fb)$.My solution depends strongly on the property that the elements $x,y \in C_P(b)$ must be conjugate in $P$. If all of the elements of $C_P(b)$ commute with $U(Fb)$ then that remains true, and the solution still works. I think you only need $Z$ to be normalized by $b$, not by all of $U(Fb)$.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I still could not get the existence of some subgroup Z of the characteristic subgroup which would be normalized by Q.

Comment: I only claimed the existence of a cyclic subgroup $Z$ that is normalized by $b$, not by your $Q = U(Fb)$. (Sorry for the confusion - I defined $Q=\langle b \rangle$ in my answer.)

Comment: That I got. I am asking that only, considering Q to be cyclic of order q.

Comment: The group $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ can be considered as a module for the group $\langle b \rangle$ over the field ${\mathbb F}_p$ of order $p$, and since $q \ne p$, it is completely reducible. Since $q|p-1$, the irreducible ${\mathbb F}_p\langle b \rangle$-modules all have dimension $1$, so (as a group) $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$, all normalized by $b$. (That is the only place where I used the assumption $q|p-1$.)

Comment: Is $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ already not an elementary abelian p-group?

Comment: since it consists of central elements of order 1 or p.

Comment: Yes of course it is - that is why it can be considered as a module over ${\mathbb F}_p$. What do you mean by "already"?

Comment: I was asking why would $Q = \langle b \rangle$ normalize a subgroup of order p in $\Omega_1(Z(P)).$ We only know that it normalizes whole $\Omega_1(Z(P)).$

Comment: Yes you asked me that and I answered it, and then you asked me whether $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ is "already" elementary abelian, and I answered that as well.

Comment: Ok. since each irreducible ⟨⟩-module has dimension 1,  the cyclic subgroups of order p in $\Omega_1(Z(P))$ are individually normalized by b. Am I right?

Comment: Well they are not necessarily all normalized by $b$, but we can write $Ω_1(())$ as a direct product of cyclic groups of order $p$, each of which is normalized by $b$.

Comment: Please let me know how can we write in that particular manner.

Comment: I have already answered that.

Comment: Hi Derek. I am really sorry for the late query. But I have a small doubt in this answer. I was wondering that in the last line of the third paragraph of your solution, you have claimed that "since  centralizes , it normalizes both  and ." It might be trivial, but I am unable to see it.

Comment: You have to prove that, if $t \in X$, then $b^{-1}tb \in X$. It is indeed trivial!

Comment: Oh. That was indeed trivial. Thanks

Comment: Hi Derek. You used a result from Aschbachers "Finite group theory" which says that if a finite group $G = A \rtimes B,$ where $(|A|,|B|) = 1$ and $B$ acts faithfully on $A$ (which is a p-group), then $A = C_A(B)[A,B].$ You proved the result initially considering $B = C_q$ but the question was later edited by me and then $B = V(FC_q).$ Does it still hold true that $V(FB)$ acts faithfully on $A?$ I really do not know the criteria how to check faithfulness of actions in such cases.